# Should I bother using Taxonomy when I am using Node Hierarchy as well?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am getting rather bogged down with the structure of my site. I have a taxonomy setup as well as node hierarchy, but I wonder if a taxonomy structure is kind of pointless now that I am using node hierarchy. Should I perhaps use it just for tagging and not any structure?

The main issue I am having is the URL aliases: they are being doubled up. It seems I am going to have tons of duplicate pages, now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity reference vs. taxonomy](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152162/entity-reference-vs-taxonomy)